# How to filter a range of currency values in footable?

Tags: jquery, slider, footable

That is what i need, using a range selector (ion.rangeSlider) to filter my footable that has a currency column ($100,000.00). Right now I have other filters that works fine.

The thing is that i can do it by sending a request and reloading the page or just removing all rows and then adding those from result, but the best way (i think) is to just filter it without more requests.

I am really stuck, if you have an idea how to do this please share !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

When slider change i get all the money values and convert to double by replacing `'$'` and `','` with `''`. so I compare the selected value from slider with each money value from my table and `if` it is in range i add it to footable filter, `else` just ignore it, then i trigger footable filter and send the filter string.

Hope this helps to someone else